# Generating and playing audio whilst being connected to bluetooth device

Tags: python, asynchronous, audio, python-multithreading

I'm trying to write a script that plays pure tones (fixed frequency sine waves), whilst connected to a bluetooth device. I'm using `bleak` and `asyncio` to connect to the bluetooth sensor, and want the pure tone frequency and intensity to vary depending on data sent from the sensor. I suppose I'm going to have to generate samples of the sine waves on-the-fly rather than creating lots of separate audio files beforehand.

I really don't know where to start. I've seen that there is PyAudio, soundplay, etc. But I really don't know if they can achieve what I want.

Comment: I think your best first step is to decompose the problem into more manageable chunks. If you find you are in the situation where you don't know where to start that is usually a good sign the problem could do with a little more decomposition. To get you started. Here are a couple of problems to solve, in no particular order. _How do you make a sine wave (not audio, just data)? How do you write a sine wave to a `.wav` file? How do you play an audio file in python? How do you play real-time audio in python?_ from there you may want to check the `[pyaudio]` tag on SO and sort by votes

Comment: [i.e.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyaudio?tab=Votes)

Comment: I’m not too troubled by all those seperate steps. Also like I said in the question, I will probably create the audio samples in the script rather than reading from a file since the frequency will vary continuously. It’s really about whether I can play audio in the background whilst using async/await etc for the Bluetooth

Comment: Audio will be on a high priority thread so that is absolutely fine. Though you may not have an end goal of playing via a file you will definitely pass through the steps required to do so on the way. You will want to have the constituent parts of your idea first, then you can start to approach how to glue it all together